# hack assembly program to blacken the screen

Tags: nand2tetris

So, I am reading the book The elements of computing systems (and doing the course). I am trying to write a hack assembly program to blacken the screen. Here is what I've got.

```
@16384
D=A
@current
M=D

@24576
D=A
@end
M=D

@current
D=M

(BEGIN)
@end
D=M-D

@END
D;JEQ
@current
D=M 
A=M
M=1
A=A+1
D=A
@current
M=D

@BEGIN
0;JMP

(END)
@END
0;JMP
```

Some pixels are appearing, but a) extremely slowly and b) it doesn't appear like the whole screen is being filled. Is there a way to improve the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really appropriate to just give you the answer, but here are a few tips that might help you on your way.

- Although HACK symbols are case-sensitive, using @end and @END for two
  different things is bad style because it risks confusion.
- there is a predefined symbol SCREEN that may prove useful.
- You have to set all the bits in each 16-bit word in the screen memory area. M=1 sets only one bit.
- You may find it more convenient to keep a counter of how many loops you have remaining as opposed to an ending pointer value.
- Remember that you can store the result of an operation in multiple destinations, as in MD=M-1. This is handy.
- Review the lecture 4 notes for an example of a loop. http://www.nand2tetris.org/lectures/PDF/lecture%2004%20machine%20language.pdf

Good luck!